# Tehilim Chapter 34 according to Aleph Bet

Tags: tehilim-psalms

Is there an explanation for why this chapter of tehilim was written according to the Aleph Bet, and why it skips the vav?

Comment: See Rada"k on the 1st verse. The vav is included in the pasuk that has *heh*. Rada"k doesn't explain why this is.

Comment: @DanF Sounds somewhat like an answer, if you can find an explanation why that is.

Comment: @DanF Meiri says that too. Although, he may have just gotten it from Radak.

Comment: You may not find an answer as to why this Tehillim is alphabetical. AFAIK, the Gemarah Brachot emphasizes saying Tehilla Ledavid (#145, commonly called "Ashrei") because it is alphabetical, but they don't explain why that one, among other Tehillim are alphabetical. It was a common technique to make "songs" alphabetical probably for memorization, mainly. Why David chose #34, specifically, as one of them, may not have an explanation.

Comment: [This article](http://journals.co.za/docserver/fulltext/oldtest/12/3/1022.pdf?expires=1535922912&id=id&accname=guest&checksum=F72701CDC01A54C63FE71239B903622E) addresses both questions by positing that _alphabetic thinking_ contributed to both its composition and its consumption. (The clear evocation of such a framework does away with the need to complete the acrostic, having achieved it sufficiently with the preponderant pattern.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Radak there explains that it was made in Aleph Bet order because of the happiness from his escape:

> מרוב השמחה ששמח דוד בהנצלו עשה שירה זו באל״ף בי״ת

As noted in the comments by DanF, Radak notes that the vav line is included in the hei line of:

> הביטו אליו ונהרו **ופניהם** אל יחפרו

This is not uncommon in piyutim, songs, and even tehillim, etc, see, for example the comments [to this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64152/%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%95-%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95-%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%95-why-three-things-that-begin-with-a-%D7%AA/87756#87756).